# References for the newtonian potential

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, poissons-equation

I am looking for reference for the newtonian potential, the only one I've found is chapter 4 of Elliptic partial differential equations of second order by Gilbarg and Trudinger but I find it very difficult to understand, and I haven't been able to find references in the internet. I am especially interested in its Holder regularity.

Comment: Do you still want notes? I'm almost finished with typing up notes which follows the relevant bits of chapters 2, 4, 6 of G&T to prove interior Schauder estimates.

Comment: @ZackFox: I’m interested 

Comment: Ok, then I will post it as an answer once I am finished typing it up.

Comment: @ZackFox Yes, i'm interested. I haven't been able to find any easier reference. I was specifically interesting in the Schauder estimates using potential theory but since I didn't find any other reference I studied another proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes are here:  https://jianhaoti.github.io/Notes_on_Schauder_Estimates.pdf. Feel free to me any with corrections (I'm sure there are many to be made).

Comment: A wonderful contribution. I hope your understanding was deepened in the process.